# Torrent ports and firewalls

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, port, bittorrent, utorrent

I use this uTorrent program, under its settings 'Listening port' I set up a port of 46301, and also open that port in firewall. But whoever connects to me to leech, they connect to random ports varying from 59000-59999, and of course my firewall blocks all that, so they cannot connect.

So, why don't they connect to my local port of 46301 instead they are connecting to random ports under TCP? Looks like they connect to that port only under UDP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have unchecked "Randomize port each start" in connection preferences.

Comment: Yes, it is unchecked.

Comment: From utorrent FAQ:

"My firewall is reporting connections being made by µTorrent on a port besides the one I selected.

Only incoming connections use the port you selected in µTorrent, for both TCP and UDP. Outgoing connections use a random local port; this is simply the way Windows functions. It's not a bug."

If your firewall supports UPNP, you can check it por mapping the ports automatically.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the corresponding FAQ:

> Only incoming connections use the port you selected in µTorrent, for both TCP and UDP. Outgoing connections use a random local port; this is simply the way Windows functions. It's not a bug.
>
> If you have a firewall, you must allow all outgoing traffic on TCP and UDP.

[Source](http://www.utorrent.com/help/faq/network#faq1)